# Tile a 1 x n walkway with 4 different types of tiles...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Suppose you are trying to tile a 1 x n walkway with 4 different types of tiles: a red 1 x 1 tile, a blue 1 x 1 tile, a white 1 x 1 tile, and a black 2 x 1 tile

a. Set up and explain a recurrence relation for the number of different tilings for a sidewalk of length n.

b. What is the solution of this recurrence relation?

c. How long must the walkway be in order have more than 1000 different tiling possibilities?

This is a problem on my test review and I have no idea how to approach it. We did a similar example in class but only using 1x1 tiles that were all the same (no separate tile colors or sizes). Any help/hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

My initial thought is something along the lines of finding all the ways to use the 1 x 1 tiles then multiplying that by 3 to consider each color variant (don't know how the 2x1 factors in to this though).

Comment: Consider the four possibilities for the first 1 by 1 tile and thus set up the recurrence.

Comment: Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to tile a walkway of length $n$. Note that $a_1=3$ and $a_2=10$.   Let $n\ge 2$. Can you show that $a_n=3a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$? Can you then solve this recurrence?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have a tiling of length $n+2$. This can be built from:

- a tiling of length $n+1$ followed by a single tile; OR
- a tiling of length $n$ followed by a double tile

Let $T_n$ be the number of different ways of tiling a $1\times n$ space. Then for $n\ge1$

$$T_{n+2}=T_{n+1}T_1+T_n=3T_{n+1}+T_n \tag{1}$$

and for the "base" cases: $T_1=3,\:T_2=10$. Then by (1)

$$\begin{array}{l}
T_3=33 \\
T_4=109 \\
T_5=360 \\
T_6=1189
\end{array}$$

So the hallway must be at least six units long for 1000+ different tiling possibilities.

---

The recursion is Fibonacci-like and can be written in matrix form as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}T_{n+2}\\T_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}T_{n+1}\\T_{n}\end{bmatrix}$$

from which the characteristic equation is $(3-\lambda)(-\lambda)-1\times1=0 \implies \lambda^2-3\lambda-1=0$ which has solutions $\lambda=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$

So we seek a formula for $T_n$ of the form $T_n=a\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n+b\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n$. Substituting for some values of $T_n$, e.g. $T_3,T_4$ to be safe, you can solve to get

$$T_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\left\{\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^{n+1}\right\}$$

It turns out that this formula works for $n=1,2$ as well even though the recursion didn't cover these cases. The formula can be proven by induction.

---

### Appendix - Obtaining a Closed-Form Solution

In the formula $T_n=a\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n+b\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n$ let $a=a_1+a_2\sqrt{13},\:b=b_1+b_2\sqrt{13}$ (with $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ all rational numbers). Then from $T_1=3,T_2=10$ we get:

$$\begin{align}
T_1&=(a_1+a_2\sqrt{13})\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^1+(b_1+b_2\sqrt{13})\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^1&=3 \\
T_2&=(a_1+a_2\sqrt{13})\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^2+(b_1+b_2\sqrt{13})\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^2&=10
\end{align}$$

and from this (by equating rational multiples of $1,\sqrt{13}$) we obtain four simultaneous equations:

$$\begin{array}{rccccccccc}
T_1[1]: & 3a_1 &+ &13a_2 &+ &3b_1  &- &13b_2 &= &6 \\
T_1[\sqrt{13}]: & a_1 &+ &3a_2 &- &b_1 &+ &3b_2 &= &0 \\
T_2[1]: & 11a_1 &+ &39a_2 &+ &11b_1  &- &39b_2 &= &20 \\
T_1[\sqrt{13}]: & 3a_1 &+ &11a_2 &- &3b_1 &+ &11b_2 &= &0 \\
\end{array}$$

with solution $a_1=b_1=\frac{1}{2},\:a_2=\frac{3}{26},b_2=-\frac{3}{26}$. So with a little manipulation

$$\begin{align}
T_n&=\tfrac{1}{2}(1+\tfrac{3}{13}\sqrt{13})\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n + \tfrac{1}{2}(1-\tfrac{3}{13}\sqrt{13})\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n \\[2ex]
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{13}+3}{2}\right)\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n + \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{2}\right)\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n \\[2ex]
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\left\{\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^{n+1}\right\}
\end{align}$$

Comment: This follows the example we did in class. I just want to be sure I completely understand. Where you are multiplying Tn+1 by 3 is that to account for the 3 different types of 1 x 1 tiles? Otherwise I am not sure where this takes into account the different colored tiles.

Comment: @D.Peterson - that's exactly correct. And patterns are being enumerated from a given end of the walkway to the other, e.g. WRB is different to BRW.

Comment: I'm still a little confused in regards to part b. It asks for the "solution" of the recurrence relation. Would the set of values we find starting at T1 through T6 be consider the solution or is it referring to something else entirely?

Comment: Reviewing my notes I believe that solution is referring to a closed form solution. I'm not really sure how to reach that.

Comment: @D.Peterson - it's tricky if you want to go to the trouble of diagonalising the matrix via its eigenvectors, etc. It's easier if you assume a form for the solution being a linear combination of powers of the eigenvalues, and then use two different values to solve for the coefficients. Note that $a$ and $b$ will "absorb" inaccurate assumptions such as using the wrong exponents and the like. Or if you compute the powers of either eigenvalue (say $\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2}$) you can notice that the $T_n$ show up as coefficients of $\sqrt{13}$.

Comment: Okay i see it now we worked through it w/o using matrices. Isn't it also true that you could factor out an exponent of the n so it is raised to the power of n-1 since the a and b will absorb it, as you stated. I thought that might make it nicer to calculate to work with a power of 0. for T1

Comment: @D.Peterson - It's worth a try, although the symmetry will disappear, i.e. $a\ne -b$ then. If you're after a simpler formula, there's one that involves rounding off a single exponential (since $-1<\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{2}<0$ the second term rapidly tends to $0$ in alternating fashion): $T_n=\lfloor \frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}(\frac{3+\sqrt{13}}{2})^{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor$. The addition of $\frac{1}{2}$ is to make the floor function simulate rounding off to the nearest integer.

Comment: I know it doesn't come out to something pretty but I went to my professor to confirm that the recurrence relation was correct and it was. I'm at the point of plugging in the initial conditions into the recurrence relation, but seem to hit a dead end when combining the two equations...

Comment: Could you show me the steps behind substituting the initial conditions into the auxillary equation to reach the closed form solution, im having trouble recreating it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Call the number of tilings of length $n$ $t_n$, then to get a tiling of length $n$, you take one of length $n - 1$ and add a red, a white or a blue tile (3 ways); add a black tile to one of length $n - 2$. I.e.:

$\begin{equation*}
  t_{n + 2}
    = 3 t_{n + 1} + t_n
\end{equation*}$

Directly we find $t_0 = 1$, $t_1 = 3$.

Define the generating function:

$\begin{equation*}
  T(z)
    = \sum_{n \ge 0} t_n z^n
\end{equation*}$

Take the recurrence, multiply by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize resulting sums:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n \ge 0} t_{n + 2} z^n
    &= 3 \sum_{n \ge 0} t_{n + 1} z^n
         + \sum_{n \ge 0} t_n z^n \\
  \frac{T(z) - t_0 - t_1 z}{z^2}
    &= 3 \frac{A(z) - t_0}{z} + A(z)
\end{align*}$

Solve for $A(z)$, split into partial fractions:

$\begin{align*}
  T(z)
    &= \frac{1}{1 - 3 z - z^2} \\
    &= \frac{2 (\sqrt{13} + 3)}{\sqrt{13}} 
         \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{2}{3 + \sqrt{13}} z}
         + \frac{2 (\sqrt{13} - 3)}{\sqrt{13}} 
              \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{2}{3 - \sqrt{13}} z}
\end{align*}$

Need to extract the coefficients from these geometric series:

$\begin{equation*}
  [z^n] T(z)
    = \frac{2 (\sqrt{13} + 3)}{\sqrt{13}}
         \cdot \left( \frac{2}{3 + \sqrt{13}} \right)^n
        + \frac{2 (\sqrt{13} - 3)}{\sqrt{13}}
             \cdot \left( \frac{2}{3 - \sqrt{13}} \right)^n
\end{equation*}$

Note that:

$\begin{align*}
  \frac{2 (\sqrt{13} + 3)}{\sqrt{13}}
    &= 2.8321 \\
  \frac{2 (\sqrt{13} - 3)}{\sqrt{13}}
    &= 1.1679 \\
  \frac{2}{3 + \sqrt{13}}
    &= 0.30278 \\
  \frac{2}{3 - \sqrt{13}}
    &= 3.3028
\end{align*}$

Note that already by $n = 1$ the first term is less than 1, so a very good approximation is $t_n = 1.1679 \cdot 3.3028^n$. To get $t_n = 1000$, you need:

$\begin{align*}
   1000 &= 1.1679 \cdot 3.3028^n \\
   n    &= 5.65  
\end{align*}$

Thus you need at least length 6.