# Tile 1xn walkway with selective repetition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Consider the following problem:

3 1x1 tiles (T1, T2, and T3) - let's call them blue, red, yellow - are used to tile a 1xN walkway. The question is: How many possible ways are there to construct a walkway N units long while ensuring that there are no blue tiles next to each other?

Obviously the question is trivial without the final condition, but with it included it becomes much harder. Looking for a) both an open and closed-form formula for walkway N, and b) a generalization of the problem if possible. I'm interested to see how the problem behaves for NxN walkways, different conditions and Nx1/1xN/NxN tiles.

Preemptively: Not a duplicate of [Tile a 1 x n walkway with 4 different types of tiles...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456837/tile-a-1-x-n-walkway-with-4-different-types-of-tiles?newreg=8a718fde97df4d54896afab0721f3465) - this question considers exclusion, extending its bounds.

Comment: First thoughts (which may already have occurred to you). For each $k$ count the number of tilings with exactly $k$ nonadjacent blue tiles. (The sum of those counts is known - it's Fibonacci). Then fill in the remaining spaces at will. Comment not an answer since I haven't worked it out and don't expect too. It might not be easy.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for your thoughts - will try this.

Comment: The simplest case is given by [OEIS A028859](https://oeis.org/A028859). The recurrence relation is $a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1} + 2a_n$ with $(a_0,a_1) = (1,3)$. When you try to construct a $n+2$ tiling. If the first tile is R/G, there is no restriction on what the remaining $n+1$ tiles are. This contributes $2a_{n+1}$ to $a_{n+2}$. Otherwise, the first tile is $B$ and second tile need to be either R/G. there will be no more restriction on the remaining $n$ tiles. This contributes $2a_n$ to $a_{n+2}$. This is  how you setup the recurrence relation. The rest is figure out what $a_0,a_1$ are.